# Automatically import data from Google spreadsheet using feeds module

Tags: 7, feeds, importing-exporting

I have data in a Google docs spreadsheet. To import that data I currently have to download the spreadsheet as a csv file and then import using the Feeds module.

What I am trying to work out is if there is someway to automate the process? Is there some way to have feeds access the spreadsheet directly from Google docs?

Would appreciate some step by step instructions on how to set this up. Note that I already have feeds setup to manually import a csv file, so the issue at hand is how can I set it up so that feeds can retrieve the data directly from Google docs at regular intervals?

Note that the data is stored as regular Google doc spreadsheet, so solution needs to make sure that the document retrieved is in CSV format (is that possible by using a certain URLs structure?)

Answer (score 6):

Sorry, bit late to the party. How I solved this was:

- Publish the file to the web using the option in Google Sheets' file menu. This gets you a special link to an always up-to-date version with the format of your choice. I used CSV.
- Select HTTP fetcher as fetcher.
- Select appropriate parser (CSV in my case) and set up mapping
- Set up periodical imports.
- Enter the URL you got from Google Sheets as source when importing.

Your updates to the Google Sheets file will be imported with the periodical imports.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For security purposes, is there a way to ensure that only the website in question can access the data from Google docs?

Comment: Google Sheets produces a link with a unique character sequence in it, so  if you don't share that link anywhere else, no one will have access to it. Should be secure enough.